# Why does it ignore my continue in the for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, pygame, continue

```
import pygame
import player

play = player.player()
pygame.init()
time = pygame.time.Clock()
key = 0
move = ""
List =[]
pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            time_down = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move = "l"
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move = "r"
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move = "d"
                print('UNTEN')
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move = "u"
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                break
            else:
                continue
        key += 1
        play.handlerevent(event)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            time_elapsed = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - time_down) / 1000.0
            print("Nummer: ", key, "Zeit: ", time_elapsed)
            tmp = (move, key)
            List.extend(tmp)
```

Hello I'm new here and would like to know, why my for-loop doesn't react to the continue. It goes into the else branch. But just ignores the continue.

Comment: What makes you think `continue` is being ignored?

Comment: For example if I press "a" "b" or "c", My Code below is still beeing executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have it backwards: `continue` is being executed when it shouldn't be.

You need to use `elif` for your sequence of conditions. Your `else:` block is only associated with the last `if` condition. So if the key is `K_LEFT` it will go into the `else:` block and continue, instead of executing the rest of the loop.

```
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move = "l"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move = "r"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move = "d"
                print('UNTEN')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move = "u"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                break
            else:
                continue
```

This way, the `else:` block will be executed only when none of the `if` conditions succeeded.

Comment: i tried it and it makes no difference, I also did a print in the else case, the print is being executed but the continue isn't.

Comment: the same thing happens to my break

Comment: Are you sure you understand what `continue` does? It means it skips over everything starting with `key += 1`, and goes to the next event.

Comment: than its my bad sorry, i thought the ```contnue``` would go to the next for loop